# Multithreaded FTP server socket VC++

Tags: multithreading, sockets, visual-c++, ftp

I am writing a basic FTP client server code in VC++ with multithreading.

The code works fine with single client but it doesn't work for 2 clients. I don't know how socket keep information for multiple clients.
If I do CD from on client it reflects in other one too. I mean if two different clients cannot work on different server directory.

May be something very basic I am missing here due to my lack of knowledge of socket programming.

code to accept connections:

```
   void acceptUserConnections()
{
    calen=sizeof(ca);
    int thread_count = 0;
    thread t[num_threads];

    while(1)
    {
            cout<<"Accepting user connections: "<<endl;
            if((cs=accept(serverSocket,&ca.generic,&calen))==INVALID_SOCKET)
                throw "Couldn't accept connection\n";

            string userAddress(inet_ntoa(ca.ca_in.sin_addr));

            thread_count = thread_count +1;
            t[thread_count] = thread(handleUserConnection, cs);
            t[thread_count].detach();
            //handleUserConnection(clientSocket);
        }
    }
}
```

to handle:

```
        void handleUserConnection(SOCKET clientSocket)
{
           if (strcmpi(command.c_str(),"PWD")==0)
            {
                ftpPWD(clientSocket);
            }
}
```

for CD

```
    void ftpCD(string directory, SOCKET clientSocket)
{
        memset(szbuffer,'\0',1024);
        if(!SetCurrentDirectory(directory.c_str()))
        {
            cout<<strerror(errno)<<endl;
            sprintf(szbuffer,"System cannot find the specified directory.");
            if(send(clientSocket,szbuffer,1024,0) == SOCKET_ERROR)
                throw SEND_FAILED_MSG;
        }
        else
        {
            sprintf(szbuffer,"Directory changed successfully.");
            if(send(clientSocket,szbuffer,1024,0) == SOCKET_ERROR)
                throw SEND_FAILED_MSG;
        }

}
```

for PWD

```
void ftpPWD(SOCKET clientSocket)
{
        memset(szbuffer,'\0',1024);
        int nBufferLength =GetCurrentDirectory(MAX_PATH, pwd);
        if(!nBufferLength)
        {
            sprintf(szbuffer,"Failed to get current directory");
            if(send(clientSocket,szbuffer,1024,0) == SOCKET_ERROR )
                throw SEND_FAILED_MSG;
        }
        else
        {
            sprintf(szbuffer,(string(pwd)).c_str());
            if(send(clientSocket,szbuffer,1024,0) == SOCKET_ERROR )
                throw SEND_FAILED_MSG;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: There seems to be chunks of stuff missing? For instance, where does 'handleUserConnection' thread function read its command?  Where is command declared?  Somewhere there should be a while loop that reads stuff from the client?

Comment: @Martin: I posted only the required details. The handleUserConnection method reads the request from the client and fetches the command and then matches then with if else. Yes, all this is done under a while loop.

Comment: A current directory is a process-wide notion. `SetCurrentDirectory` changes the directory for the whole process; `GetCurrentDirectory` will report the directory set by the most recent call to `SetCurrentDirectory`, no matter which thread executed it. Essentially, it's a global variable - you can't use it to represent per-connection information.

Comment: @Igor: Thanks Igor.  Then it's there a way to overcome this issue?

Comment: Don't use `SetCurrentDirectory`. Save the string that the client sets as its current directory in some per-connection data structure. Build full paths, using this string, when you need to actually access files, in the context of a particular connection.

Comment: Thanks again :). Even I had this thought but it seemed to me a crude way to do this.   Don't know how this is done in real FTP servers. For now this will help.